# Rails fixtures magical columns doesn't work anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, fixtures

created some fixtures yesterday and they worked great.
Today i'll tried to rerun these fixtures, but there seems to be a problem with the magical columns. Here's an example fixture:

```
hans:
  prename: Hans
  lastname: Meier
  admission_date: <%= Date.today %>
  user: service_user
  menu: non_veg
```

And this fixture relates in the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "user" of relation "patients"    does not exist
LINE 1: ...astname", "prename", "admission_date", "menu_id", "user") VA...
                                                         ^
: INSERT INTO "patients" ("id", "lastname", "prename", "admission_date", "menu_id", "user") VALUES (615630666, 'Meier', 'Hans', '2011-02-24', 285998188, 'service_user')
```

So it tries to insert the values which are related fixtures into the database as plain data. Does anyone knows how to avoid that?

Comment: Seems that my relationship in the patient model is the reason: there ist just a  `belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'` and not a `belongs_to :user`. Can I say the fixtures that there is a creator and that the user_id column should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, forgot to add  `:foreign_key: 'user_id'` to the model.
Now the fixtures are generated appropriate.